# Cannot start Heroku project on windows. Main class not found, and if found it cannot find other classes

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first discord bot to heroku, but it cannot find the main File.

My pom.xml looks like this:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>kostisBot</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



  <name>kostisBot</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>dv8tion</id>
    <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
    <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>



</repositories>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- Use the latest version whenever possible. -->
    <jackson.version>2.12.0</jackson.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codesnippets4all</groupId>
      <artifactId>quick-json</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version> </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>

      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
      <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.75</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.dhiraj072</groupId>
      <artifactId>random-word-generator</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jagrosh</groupId>
      <artifactId>jda-utilities</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
      <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1_255</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <!-- This tells Maven to include all dependencies -->
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>src.main.java.Kostis.App.java</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>15</source>
          <target>15</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <appName>kostisbot</appName>
          <processTypes>
            <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* src.main.java.Kostis.App.java</web>
          </processTypes>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

`

My proc file looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* src.main.java.Kostis.App.java
```

this is the path for Main App [here][1]

Way before i think main loaded but all the other classes failed:
[enter image description here][2]

I'd appreciate any help. I have been trying to run my app for a while now and nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNQ0B.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqMyz.png